# php code not fetching form input values?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form in a html document and what I'm trying to do is  when someone submit this form it goes to file "total.php" and in total.php file I calculated (multiplication of values and the result reflects on html page but it is not working.)

**Here is html and javascript code**

Working of form :

when user choose his level ,let say 1 then other two fields will be auto fill using javascript mentioned in this code ,so for level 1 other two fields will be filled as

No. Of person = 3 and Earning of person = $5 . after this there is button named as calculate earning , once user clicks that button it goes to file total.php as "action of form = total.php"

```
<script>
             function getPerson(select) {
  var form = select.form;
  form.ref_person.value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute('per');
  form.earn_person.value = select.value;}                            
            </script>
                        <form id="calc" method="post" action="total.php" target="total">
                          <fieldset>
                          <legend>Person and earning</legend>
                          <label class="fhead">CHOOSE YOUR LEVEL :</label> 
                          <select name="choose" id="personSelect" onchange="getPerson(this)">
                                    <option value="" selected>Choose</option>
                                  <option per="3" value="$5">1</option>
                                  <option per="9" value="$4">2</option>
                                  <option per="27" value="$4">3</option>
                          </select> 
                           <br>
                          <label  class="fhead" for="personNumber">No. Of person:</label>
                          //first  input field
                              <input type="text" name="ref_person"id="personNumber" class="field"  readonly="readonly">
                            <br />

                          <label  class="fhead" for="personEarning">Earning of person:</label>
                              //second  input field
                            <input type="text" name="earn_person" id="personEarning"  class="field"  readonly="readonly">
                          </fieldset>

                          <input style=" float:right; margin-right:90px;"  name="submit" value="Calculate Earnings" type="submit"> 

                        </form>

                                //This iframe tag helps in reflecting the result of the calculation I did in total.php .

                             <iframe src="total.php" name="total" width="100%"frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

**Here is my total.php code**

Now in total php I fetched input values of form to calculate stuff and result of this should reflect on html page but unfortunately it is not wokring.

I don't know where I'm making mistake.

```
//fetching input values from form
<?php
$ref_person=$_POST['ref_person'];
$earn_person=$_POST['earn_person'];

//required calcualtion    
$total =$ref_person * $earn_person;
$monthly = $total; 
$yearly = $monthly * 12;
?> 

<This is start tr tag>
    <this is td tag>
    <b style="color:#FFF">Monthly Income: $<?php if (empty($total) || $total == 0 || $total == 0.00) { echo "0"; } 
    else { echo "$monthly"; } ?>.00</b>
<This is end of td tag >

</This is end of tr tag>

<This is start  tr tag >

    <This is td tag >
    <b style="color:#FFF">Yearly Income: $<?php if (empty($total) || $total == 0 || $total == 0.00) { echo "0"; } 
    else { echo "$yearly"; } ?>.00</b>
<This is end of td tag >

</This is end of tr tag>
```

Comment: I think you need to take a look at your js function again. You pass a param called `select` as the parameter and then try to use that in all manner of ways - just looks wrong

Comment: Looks like you are trying to update 'total.php', but it won't refresh the iframe. It won't because you will have to refresh the whole page. It will not work this way. Try AJAX.

Comment: @RamRaider , you might be right but how to fix this part.       and "Daniel" actually it is not fetching values from form , reflecting these values on html page is diffrent part .

Comment: @fred, thanks for reminding me , let me do this .

Comment: @ninja You're welcome and *Welcome to Stack* ;-)

Comment: @fred , Thanks , Cheers!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly the javascript function seemed to work so please accept my apologies for doubting it. I think you could change the `total.php` code to:

```
<?php
    $ref_person=intval( $_POST['ref_person'] );
    $earn_person=intval( $_POST['earn_person'] );

    $total = $ref_person * $earn_person;
    $monthly = $total; 
    $yearly = $monthly * 12;

    /* you didn't return or echo any value */
    echo $yearly > 0 && !empty( $yearly ) ? 'Total Yearly: $'.$yearly : '';
?>
```

I changed, in test, the js function that shown below:

```
        function getPerson(n) {
            var form = n.parentNode.parentNode;
            form.ref_person.value = n.options[ n.options.selectedIndex ].getAttribute('per');
            form.earn_person.value = n.value;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks !!! Ramraider, Now It's working , I guess the mistake was I wasn't casting it while fetching values ?? Btw thanks!! a lot!! for taking a look at my code and helping me .

Comment: Though, I just checked when I put " $ " in option tag <option per="3" value="$5">1</option> or in javascript "  form.earn_person.value = '$'+n.value;" then it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of mistakes. Assuming your JS is working and you have values, then probably you will get the strings that cannot be casted to integer

Option values are wrong there should not be $ before digit, you can use $ between  not in value because then in PHP it will be casted to integer 0 when you do multiplication and also because numeric vars like $1 are actually [backreferences](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php) in PHP then it can cause warnings.

Change

```
<option per="3" value="$5">1</option>
<option per="9" value="$4">2</option>
<option per="27" value="$4">3</option>
```

to

```
<option per="3" value="5">$5</option>
<option per="9" value="4">$4</option>
<option per="27" value="4">$4</option>
```

Also you have mistake in your HTML. There is no space between attributes here:

```
 <input type="text" name="ref_person"id="personNumber"
```

Your total.php won't work that way. Maybe if you kept data in session and then refresh iframe periodically it would make sense.

Comment: yeah , JS is working fine and yes you right I put that $ into java script code "  form.earn_person.value = '$' +select.value;" and removed from value still total.php file is not calculating as I used echo for $total variable to check if it is fetching input values or not ?

Comment: you were right that $ thing was creating issue even when I write it in javascript , now I mentioned "$" in input tag of form and it is working fine. Thanks!!